# Why doesn't interning work on copies of a string?

Tags: c#

Given:

```
        object literal1 = "abc";
        object literal2 = "abc";

        object copiedVariable = string.Copy((string)literal1);

        if (literal1 == literal2)
            Console.WriteLine("objects are equal because of interning");//Are equal

        if(literal1 == copiedVariable)
            Console.WriteLine("copy is equal");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("copy not eq");//NOT equal
```

These results imply that `copiedVariable` is not subject to string interning.  Why?

Is there a circumstance where its useful to have equivalent strings that are not interned or is this behavior due to some language detail?

Comment: That is the desired behavior, IMO. If you want the result interned, call `Intern` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think about it, the interning of strings is a process that it triggered at compile time on literals. Which implies that:

- it is implicit when you assign/bind a literal to a variable
- it is implicit when you copy a reference (i.e. string a = some_other_string_variable;)

On the other hand, if you create an instance of a string *manually* - at run-time by using a StringBuilder, or by Copy-ing, than you have to specifically request to intern it by invoking the [Intern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) method of the String class.

Even in the remarks section of the documentation it is stated that:

> The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a
>   table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to
>   each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in
>   your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a
>   particular value only exists once in the system. For example, if you
>   assign the same literal string to several variables, the runtime
>   retrieves the same reference to the literal string from the intern
>   pool and assigns it to each variable.

And the documentation for the [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copy.aspx) method of the String class states that it:

> Creates **a new instance** of String with the same value as a specified
>   String.

which implies that it's not going to just return a reference to the same string (from the intern pool). Again, if it did there wouldn't be much use for it then, would there?!

Answer (score 1):

Some languages requires the result be a copy for certain methods/procedures.

For example in `substring` type methods. The semantics would then be the same, even if if you call `foo.substring(0, foo.length)` (and how you would probably implement `stringcopy`).

**Note**: IIRC*, this is NOT the case with .NET's implementation of `string.Substring` though. It is not really clear from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) either. (see below)

It returns:

> A string that is equivalent to the substring of length length that
>   begins at startIndex in this instance, or Empty if startIndex is equal
>   to the length of this instance and length is zero.

It notes:

> This method does not modify the value of the current instance.
>   Instead, it returns a new string with length characters starting from
>   the startIndex position in the current string.

**UPDATE**

I remember correctly, it does indeed do a check with `string InternalSubString(int startIndex, int length, bool fAlwaysCopy)` if `fAlwaysCopy` is not `false`. `Substring` passes `false` to this method.

**UPDATE 2**

It looks like `string.Copy` could have used `InternalSubString` and passing `true` to the aforementioned parameter, but looking at the disassembly, it seems to use a slightly more optimized version and possibly save a method call.

Sorry for the redundant information.

* The reason I remember was when implementing the `substring` procedure for IronScheme, which the R6RS specification requires to make a copy :)